# jQuery pagination issue with https (HTTP 301 Error)

Tags: codeigniter, https, base-url

I am using ajax jquery pagination library.

If in config file base_url defined as `https://` then pagination is not working and showing `301 Moved Permanently`, but if it's `http://` then pagination is working.

What could be the problem?

Comment: add more details. rename title to hint what the error is (HTTP 301). what's your server configuration? are you sure it's supporting HTTPS? remove redundant sentences (I am facing a problem. please help). what pagination library you are using?

Comment: added use_ssl(TRUE). problem resolved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

added use_ssl(TRUE). problem resolved